# How to grant permission to delete X509Certificate2 from a store

Tags: c#, asp.net, permissions, x509certificate

I have some code which deletes certain certificates from the "TrustedPeople" store on the local machine. The code to do this:

```
var serverClientStore = new X509Store(StoreName.TrustedPeople, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
serverClientStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);

X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = serverClientStore.Certificates;
X509Certificate2Collection currentCerts = certCollection.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, myCertName, true);
foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in currentCerts)
{
    serverClientStore.Remove(cert);
}
```

This code works for me when I run my tests, 'cos they're running as my local user account. However, when I run the code from the web application, running as the "NETWORK SERVICE" user, it fails on the line `serverClientStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);` with an "Access is denied" error.

But - I don't know how to set the permissions for "NETWORK SERVICE" or any other user to be able to read/write from the store. I can see stuff about giving permissions to individual certificates, but nothing for the store.

I tried giving full permissions to `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` to Network service, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you already found an answer to your question?

Comment: Nope - sorry. I went down a different road that removes the need for certs in the end, coulnd't work this one out